# How can I "double return" through multiple functions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return, python-asyncio

I have three functions that "trickle down" and get called within another like so:

````
async def start_swings(self, server, user):
    try:
        while self.jailed[server.id][user.id]['current'] != 0:
            await self.get_question(server, user)
        else:
            await self.escape_jail(server, user)
    except KeyError:  # User isn't jailed
        pass

async def get_question(self, server, user):
    rnd = random.choice(range(2))
    if rnd == 0:
        await self.swing_math(server, user)
    elif rnd == 1:
        await self.swing_reverse(server, user)

async def swing_math(self, server, user):
    num1 = random.randint(1, 1000)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 1000)
    ops = ['+', '-']
    op = random.choice(ops)
    ans = int(eval(str(num1) + op + str(num2)))
    await self.bot.send_message(user, "**\N{HAMMER} It's going to take you `{}` more swings to break free.**\n```What is {} {} {}?```\n*I might doze off if you take too long to answer. If you don't get a reply from me within a few seconds, type `>swing`. If you try to use `>swing` as a way to reset your current question, you'll get a cooldown penalty.*".format(self.jailed[server.id][user.id]['current'], num1, op, num2))
    resp = await self.bot.wait_for_message(author=user)
    resp = resp.clean_content
    if resp == str(ans):
        await self.bot.send_message(user, "Correct. \N{WHITE HEAVY CHECK MARK} Take a swing.")
        self.jailed[server.id][user.id]['current'] -= 1
        dataIO.save_json('data/jail/jailed.json', self.jailed)
    elif resp == ">swing":
        return
    else:
        await self.bot.send_message(user, "Wrong. \N{CROSS MARK} Let me put that brick back in place.")
        self.jailed[server.id][user.id]['current'] += 1
        dataIO.save_json('data/jail/jailed.json', self.jailed)
````

In the third function, you'll see this statement:

```
elif resp == ">swing":
    return
```

How can I get that to effectively "double return" so that it instead returns to `start_swings` instead of `get_questions`? I am fairly new to Python and don't know exactly what to call this. I'm effectively trying to get execution of this script to stop completely at this area of the code:

```
elif resp == ">swing":
   return
```

… rather than just having it return to the last function called.

Comment: return -1, do a check in outer function like "if this returns -1, return"

Answer (score 4):

You cannot "pop" the stack manually like you could do in old times basic, but you can use an *exception* (even if it's considered bad practice if the exception isn't thrown "exceptionnally"):

Inherit from Exception:

```
class DoubleReturnException(Exception):
     pass
```

Install the handler:

```
    while self.jailed[server.id][user.id]['current'] != 0:
        try:
            await self.get_question(server, user)
        except DoubleReturnException:
            pass
    else:
```

Then instead of returning, just:

```
raise DoubleReturnException
```

to return to the `except` part of the handler (whatever the number of calls are).

Defining your own exception is *necessary* because it ensures that the program returns for this reason, and not for a `ValueError` or any other exception that the program could throw.

That must remain an exceptional case. Programming by throwing exceptions everywhere lead to "spaghetti code" and somehow reinstates the evil `goto` statement. You may find that interesting in the last stages of a stable product, when you cannot break all the (flawed) design for a particular case (but personally I never had to use tricks like that).